# Wrong subversion binaries in /bin /usr/bin

Tags: software-installation, osx, alias, subversion

I am woking on a Mac and recently updated Xcode, within in this update it installs the latest version of `subversion 1.9.x` as the core installation. This would be fine but at work we use `1.8.x` and this newer version is incompatible.

Ideally I would like to change the core subversion back to 1.8.x but I am not clear on how to progress.What I have done so far is install the correct version via package manager (Homebrew) into `/usr/local/opt/subversion`.

This is fine for my IDE because I can point to the ./bin folder. However, if I want to work in the terminal, which I do often the version is 1.9.x.

As a workaround I have created an alias in my `./bash_profile` as follows 
`alias svn=/usr/local/opt/subversion@1.8/bin/svn`.

Now when I open the terminal and run `svn --version` I get the following.

`svn, version 1.8.16 (r1740329)
   compiled Apr  2 2017, 22:11:27 on x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0`

Which is perfect but I feel I am missing something, there are other binaries which I use from time to time in there and I am loathe to alias them all. It feels like there should be a better way but I am not too confident moving things around at root level.

Is it possible to reassign the working version of subversion. Maybe something like `use svn --path ....`.

Comment: Look for wherever your PATH is set and put `/usr/local/opt/subversion@1.8/bin` at the front of the PATH.

Comment: It had crossed my mind, do you mean like this. `export PATH=/usr/local/opt/subversion@1.8/bin/:/usr/bin:/bin:$PATH`. Still not really got my head around these entries.

Comment: Yes, and to make it permanent, put that `export` command in one of your `bash` start up files.  (To determine which one, it would be best to ask someone who is familiar with how Macs are typically configured.)

Answer (score 0):

While editing appending the `$PATH` environment variable is an option in terms of setting the order of preference for the binaries you would like to be used. This may not be entirely necessary.

When you run `svn up` from the terminal in a working copy with a mismatched subversion you will get the following message.

`svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command`

Past experience of blindly running commands makes me nervous, but after investigating a number of co-workers machines it is clear that the incompatibility is with the working copy and not with the VCS server.

To resolve the mismatch you can simply run `svn upgrade`. After this you will be able to run `svn up` and the update should proceed without problem.

If all else fails you can still force a specific version of the `svn` binary to be used by setting the path to your subversion folder in the `$PATH` environment variable.

e.g. `export PATH=/usr/local/opt/subversion@1.8/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:$PATH`

What I didn't really take the time to understand before now is that `$PATH` contains the location of any binaries you wish to be accessible from the command line. The closer to the front of the string your binary of choice is, determines the order in which they are selected.

If a folder is no longer available I believe it should cascade to the next location.